# seq function with stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, seq

I have a melted data.frame with 3 variables.

```
      rn      variable       value
1     1 mhits_L$fhits 0.002262443
2     2 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000
3     3 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000
4     4 mhits_L$fhits 0.002262443
5     5 mhits_L$fhits 0.002262443
6     6 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000
7     7 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000
8     8 mhits_L$fhits 0.002262443
9     9 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000
10   10 mhits_L$fhits 0.000000000



     rn      variable       value
1     1 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
2     2 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
3     3 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
4     4 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
5     5 mhits_H$fhits 0.004273504
6     6 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
7     7 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
8     8 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
9     9 mhits_H$fhits 0.000000000
10   10 mhits_H$fhits 0.004273504



    rn       variable       value
1     1 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
2     2 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
3     3 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
4     4 mhits_VH$fhits 0.004291845
5     5 mhits_VH$fhits 0.004291845
6     6 mhits_VH$fhits 0.004291845
7     7 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
8     8 mhits_VH$fhits 0.004291845
9     9 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
10   10 mhits_VH$fhits 0.000000000
```

I wanted to plot a smoothed plot using seq(rn):

```
ggplot(aes(x = seq(rn), y = value, color = variable)) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(y = value), position = "identity", method = "loess", span = 0.1,se = FALSE)
```

The plot appears (as shown) with each of the variables separated instead of one plot with all three having the same x axis of 0-550. Basically all three have to be superimposed on the same seq(rn) from 0-550. What am I missing? [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXX3X.png)

Comment: What were you hoping to accomplish with `seq(rn)`? Also the image didn't display in in your question. Please edit and repost so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry about that, plot added. Without the seq(), the smooth doesn't work because there are too many points? Open to other options instead of seq() - but with the seq, each variable individually looks the way I want.

Comment: It looks like you're just showing a small snippet of your data so it's hard to figure out what the issue is. Can you share the output of `data %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarize_all(range)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the issue with your data, but here's an example with some simulated data that might help.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# set siulation size
n <- 100

# simulate some data
data1 <-
  data.frame(
    rn = rep(1:n, times = 3),
    variable = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = n),
    value = c(1:n * (1 + runif(n, 0, 1)),
              1:n * (1 + runif(n, 0, 2)),
              1:n * (1 + runif(n, 0, 3)))
  )

# plot with seq
data1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(seq(rn), value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.2, se=F)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
# plot without seq
data1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rn, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = .2, se=F)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - I edited the question to include the first 10 rows of the other variables. rn goes from 1-550 for all 3 but the data looks the same for all. Without seq - looks like this (https://imgur.com/a/k6hTgqo) and I would not like it to be facet_wrap().

Comment: Why do you think that graph is wrong? It actually looks reasonable to me based on what you showed so far.

Comment: I wanted it to look like this https://imgur.com/a/xXNQ46q. Solved by pivoting the data instead of melting. No idea why that worked better. Thanks for your help!